# How to search based on Referenced Objects

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have `UserProfile` with "first name", "audit log",... fields. I want to search the collection based on `"first name", "activity On From", "activity On To"` in audit log column.

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55bb9ff454ffd80ab4d32d8e"),
        "first name" : "firstName0",
        "middle name" : "",
        "last name" : "lastName0",    
        "audit log" : [ 
            {
                "user id" : {
                    "$ref" : "userprofile",
                    "$id" : ObjectId("55bb9ff454ffd80ab4d32d90")
                },
                "action" : "Edited Date Of Birth",
                "activity on" : ISODate("2015-07-31T16:19:00.221Z")
            }, 
            {
                "user id" : {
                    "$ref" : "userprofile",
                    "$id" : ObjectId("55bb9ff454ffd80ab4d32d8e")
                },
                "action" : "Edited Gender",
                "activity on" : ISODate("2015-07-31T16:19:00.227Z")
            }
        ]
    }
```

How can I fetch like this:

> SELECT * FROM UserProfile WHERE "audit log.user id" contains (Given
>   First Name in search Box) AND

For this I tried:

```
    Datastore ds = getDatastore();

    Query<UserProfile> profileQuery = ds.createQuery(UserProfile.class);
    Query<UserProfile> auditQuery = ds.createQuery(UserProfile.class);

    profileQuery.field("_id").equal(userId);

    if (auditedBy != null) {
        auditQuery.field("first name").containsIgnoreCase(auditedBy);
        profileQuery.criteria("audit log.user id").in(auditQuery.asKeyList());
    }

    if (action != null) {
        profileQuery.field("audit log.action").containsIgnoreCase(action);
    }

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    // Need to do Range for give 2 Dates
    if (activityOnFrom != null) {

        Date activityDateFrom = formatter.parse(activityOnFrom);
        profileQuery.field("audit log.activity on").greaterThanOrEq(
                activityDateFrom);
    }

    if (activityOnTo != null) {
        Date activityDateTo = formatter.parse(activityOnTo);
        profileQuery.field("audit log.activity on").lessThanOrEq(
                activityDateTo);
    }

    UserProfile q = profileQuery.get();
```

Here output: `profileQuery` : 
`{ "$and" : [ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "55bb9ff454ffd80ab4d32d8e"}} , { "audit log.user id" : { "$in" : [ { "$ref" : "userprofile" , "$id" : { "$oid" : "55bb9ff454ffd80ab4d32d8e"}}]}} , { "audit log.action" : { "$regex" : "Edit" , "$options" : "i"}} , { "audit log.activity on" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2015-08-03T06:00:00.000Z"}}} , { "audit log.activity on" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : "2015-08-05T06:00:00.000Z"}}}]}`

Whereas `UserProfile q` contains all audit log users lists! (Without any filters). I wish to get audit user details for ObjectId : 55bb9ff454ffd80ab4d32d8e not both!

Comment: Don't know what the whole Java code is doing (this looks utterly complicated), but the approach looks right. The query. however, should be simpler: `"audit log.user id" : { "$in" : [ ObjectId("55bb9ff454ffd80ab4d32d90") ] }`.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting?  It seems like you're getting results back...

Comment: Nope @evanchooly : I am expecting only get the auditlog with user : 55bb9ff454ffd80ab4d32d90 but instead it is returning all available audit logs without caring about the filter condition of "auditedBy"

Comment: That's normal MongoDB behavior. When your query matches one element of an array, the whole document is returned. When you want to only get the array entry which triggered the match, you need to provide a list of requested fields to the query and use [the positional-operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) on the array-field. However, I don't know how to do this with Morphia because I never used it.

Comment: @Philipp: I think that is the problem anyone knows how to do fetch only the conditioned Object from all available objects in array list